# Android Studio first run, but can not click finish

Tags: flutter, android-studio, download, sdk, android-studio-2.1

[downloading components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dxdj.jpg)I have downloaded the latest android studio bundle from android site. Installation was successful, but when I run it for the first time, it shows a window in the screenshot. (Android studio 2022.2.1.20-windows)It will not go beyond here. I think this should be finished. But one is not active.

what should i do. Will there be a problem if I cancel? or what to do?

Comment: any update on this? It might take time depending on your PC and network. If it still did not complete, let us know more detailed error.